# Truncating a String in Javascript (with constraints)

Tags: javascript, string, truncation

I'm working on this coding challenge from freecodecamp https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/truncate-a-string.

To complete this my code must fulfil the following 3 conditions:

1. Truncate a string (first argument) if it is longer than the given maximum string length (second argument). Return the truncated string with a ... ending.
2. The inserted three dots at the end should also add to the string length.
3. However if the given maximum string length is less than or equal to 3, then the addition of the three dots does not add to the string length in determining the truncated string.

I'm able to fulfil the first 2 conditions, but for some reason my code throws up an error when I give a test case where length of the string is less than or equal to 3...

Example:
truncateString("Absolutely Longer", 2) should return "Ab..." but instead returns "Absolutely Longe..."

Please help. My code is at https://gist.github.com/adityatejas/7857c0866f67783e71a1c9d60d3beed8.

```
function truncateString(str, num)
{
  var truncatedStr = '';
  if (str.length > num)
  {
    truncatedStr = str.slice(0, num-3) + "...";
    return truncatedStr;    
  }
  else if (num <= 3)
  {
    truncatedStr = str.slice(0, num) + "...";
    return truncatedStr;
  }
  else return str;
}
```

`truncateString("Adi", 1);`

Comment: 1) Post code here 2) Give a *specific question* and don't make us do your work. Once you have a specific question we'll be glad to help 3) What's the 'error'

Comment: Well you code says if it is less than 3, add dots.

Comment: Ok @AndrewL have edited my error message and my code in to my original question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @epascarello have modified my code but still am not able to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a function that takes in two parameters, a string of your choice and a maximum length. Based on the conditions, we need three scenarios.

1. When the given string exceeds the maximum and the maximum is less than or equal to 3. In this case, the ellipsis is not added to the end of the string. We take a slice of the string from the first character (position zero) until three less than the max and add the ellipses.
2. When the given string exceeds the maximum and the maximum is greater than 3. In this case, our strings inherently get longer. We update the slice parameters to go from the first index to the length of the string and add the ellipses on top of that.
3. Otherwise, just return the string as it is, because it does not exceed the maximum length.

```js
var truncatedString = document.getElementById("truncated-string");

function truncateString(myString, strLength) {
    if (myString.length > strLength) {
        if (strLength <= 3) {
            return myString.slice(0, strLength - 3) + "...";
        }
        else {
            return myString.slice(0, strLength) + "...";
        }
    }
    else {
        return myString;
    }
    
}

var userInput = prompt("Please enter a string");
var lengthLimit = prompt("Enter a maximum length");

truncatedString.innerHTML = truncateString(userInput, lengthLimit);
```

```html
<p id="truncated-string"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard. This is the same logic I attempted too. Would you be kind enough to help me learn where I missed out on? Am still not able to find it out despite comparing the my code with yours...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?:` and [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
function truncateString(str, num) {
    return str.length > num ?
        str.slice(0, num > 3 ? num - 3 : num) + "..." :
        str;
}

console.log(truncateString("Abcdefghijk", 5));
console.log(truncateString("A-", 1));
console.log(truncateString("Alpha", 5));
console.log(truncateString("Beta", 5));
console.log(truncateString("Epsilon", 3));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nina. Elegant code suggestion. Would you also mind helping me identify what i was missing just for my learning (am just starting out coding)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
function truncateString(str, num) {
if (str.length > num) {
return str.slice(0, num) + "...";}
else {
return str;}}
```